# Delete line-breaks and space in html inner text UWP

Tags: c#, html, string, text

I have to delete line break from the text in a string returned by html.
This is an example of the text with the char line break to be deleted to have a continuous string. I have to eliminate spaces: space after point, space before paragrpah (I have to just one space after point and one space before new paragrapg) and eliminate line breaks but I want to keep the paragraphs.

This is a text [string](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjedWjxtK_C80za7hRKf8SbfJdQW)

I have only tried this code:

```
string News = "StringText";
Regex.Replace(News, @"\n|\t|\r", "");
```

Using this method, the paragraph is eliminated and there are also spaces before the paragraph that begins with "Earlier this month".

How can I eliminate line breaks and keep paragraphs and leave a space only after the points?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(news, @"\r\n?|\n|[ ]{2,}", "");
```

For remove double spaces

```
"[ ]{2,}"
```

For remove line breaks

```
"\r\n?|\n"
```